# Search by brand base on category in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on laravel 5.5 project and I need to get my products base on their brand and brands has to show base on category page.

## Explanation:

I have category `x` and `xx` in each category I have products which are tagged to brands now I want to show select form of my brands image in my category page and only get brands included in that category and not all brands.

`e.g:`

In category `x` I have products tagged to brands `hp` `toshiba` and `lg` but I also have other brands which category `x` no have any product related to them, so I just want to show `hp` `toshiba` and `lg` in category `x` page.

`How I need to work?`

I want show brands Image and by clicking on each image list of that brand product shows up.

`LIVE SAMPLE`

https://www.aliexpress.com/category/1501/mother-kids.html?spm=2114.11010108.109.2.1d889209GHjrIW

> As you see in link I shared `Shop By Brands` part only brands included that category shows and by clicking on them you can see products in that category with that brand.

`My Codes`

So far I have code below as search method (which I know is not correct at all!)

```
//brand search
    public function brandsearch() {
      $brandsearch = request('search');
      $brandsearchType = request('brandsearchType');

      if(strcmp($brandsearchType, "products") == 0){
        $brands = Brand::where('title', 'like', "%{$brandsearch}%")->with('products')->get();
        return view('frontend.brandsearch', compact('brands'));
      }
    }
```

And `My Route` is:

```
//searchByBrand
Route::any('/brandsearch', 'IndexController@brandsearch');
```

This is my form.

```
<form class="search" action="/brandsearch" method="GET" role="search">
          <ul class="list-inline" name="brandsearch">
            @foreach($brands as $brand)
              <li name="brandsearchType">
                <img width="80" height="30" class="thumbnail" alt="{{$brand->title}}"src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$brand->image}}">
              </li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        {{Form::submit('Search')}}
      </form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: did u try with ajax?

Comment: @RamAnji no i didn't try ajax, but i managed to get my brands and products related to them. **the only issue still exist is to show only brands included category page that user visits.**